# How to set path for non-python dependencies of python packages?

Tags: python

The python library I'm using needs some non-python dependencies. Python recognizes them if the default path is used (/usr/bin/). But my use case requires me to build the dependencies in a specific directory.

```sh
./configure prefix= <directory>
make && make install
```

But how do I tell it to read from a custom directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Didn't work. I want python to read compiled .so files not other python modules.